# Drupal hook_menu_alter current node issues

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, module, nodes

I am developing a new module and in my hook_menu_alter() I need to detect the node currently being viewed.

Instead of using `arg(1)` to fetch the the node id from the url, I discovered I can use 
menu_get_object().

The following code works in my hook_init() but does not in hook_menu_alter():

```
$node = menu_get_object();
dpm($node);
```

Can anyone offer some insight into why that does not work and how to get the current node infomation in hook_menu_alter()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from `hook_menu`, `hook_menu_alter` etc. is cached so those functions will only be called when the caches are cleared, not for every page load. If you think about, if the menus were rebuilt on every page load the performance of the site would suffer considerably.

As such, when `hook_menu_alter` is called (which won't be from a node page), there's no node for `menu_get_object()` to give you. The way to handle these things is in the page/access callback for the menu item:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['some/path']['page callback'] = 'mymodule_page_callback';
}

function mymodule_page_callback() {
  // This is a live page so menu_get_object() is now available
  $node = menu_get_object();
}
```

From your comment I think you're trying to deny access to particular nodes based on some criteria. For this you'll want to implement your own access callback for the already existing `node/%` menu path. Something like this:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_access_callback';
}

function mymodule_access_callback($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'group') {
    if (some_function_that_determines_access($node)) {
      return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
  }

  return node_access('view', $node);
}
```

Comment: Is this solution applicable for Drupal 6?

Comment: Yes the code is actually exactly the same between Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 for this particular issue

Comment: Forgive me if I am being thick but I implemented both functions and there was no effect. Visiting http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/6, I found no matching hook_page_alter function. Am I just looking at incomplete documentation and doing something wrong in my code ???

Comment: Massive apologies, it should be `hook_menu_alter()` I managed to confuse myself :) I've fixed it in the answer now

Comment: Thank you for you patience and help but I am already setting $items['some/path']['page callback'] to false. I am developing this module to help with an issue in organic groups. I found members of one group can post into that group and groups they are not members of. This whole thing is to restrict posting by membership. So, right now I can disable a 'create post' link by $items["node/add/page]['access callback'] = FALSE. Next step was to detect the current node type and if it happens to be a group, use an OG function to check if the current user is a member. First argument is the GroupID

Comment: @sisko: I've made the update, it should give you a good starting point

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5460/discussion-between-sisko-and-clive)

Comment: @Sisko: Sorry I'm at work at the moment so can't go into chat, if you've got any follow up questions post them here or start a new question and I'll answer it later on :)

Comment: @sisko If you use `$items["node/add/page]['access callback'] = FALSE`, then no user will have access to that page, including the user #1.